# Not able to send APNS Notifications using VB.Net

Tags: ios, vb.net, json.net, apple-push-notifications

I am using below vb.net code at my .asmx service end to send notification on Apple device and to send i am using JdSoft.Apns.Notifications.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll dlls, i have created certificate for that so many time and properly created device token but still i am not able to send notifications on apple device.

Please any one check below code and suggest me where i am doing wrong and send me sample code for that would be better because using vb.net back end this is my first code to send notification on Apple device.

```
Imports JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications
Imports Newtonsoft.Json


Dim sandbox As Boolean = True
Dim p12File As String = "Certificate/Certificates.p12" '' certificate path
Dim p12FilePassword As String = ""
Dim p12Filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,     p12File)

Dim service As New NotificationService(sandbox, p12Filename, p12FilePassword, 1)

service.SendRetries = 5
service.ReconnectDelay = 1000

Dim alertNotification As New Notification(deviceToken)

alertNotification.Payload.Alert.Body = String.Format("New message again. !!!.")
alertNotification.Payload.Sound = "default"
alertNotification.Payload.Badge = 1
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MSGID", New Object() {MessageID})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MID", New Object() {MID})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MSGTYPE", New Object() {MSGTYPE})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("RID", New Object() {RID})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("RNAME", New Object() {RNAME})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MNAME", New Object() {MNAME})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MSG", New Object() {MSG})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("MSGCONTENT", New Object() {MSGCONTENT})
alertNotification.Payload.CustomItems.Add("BOOL", New Object() {BOOL})

If service.QueueNotification(alertNotification) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Notification Queued!")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Notification Failed to be Queued!")
End If
```

Comment: If you're using the sandbox, make sure your app is a development build, not production.

Comment: hi brian, yes i am using this code in development phase.